# Passing a variable from one page to another in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering if anyone could give me an idea of how to pass a variable to another page in Wordpress.
I need to be able to use the `get_the_ID();` function to set a variable which can be accessed from any page.
Would I be able to store the variable in a session or would that be a security issue?

Am I completely on the wrong track because to be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing.Any help would go a long way.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using session is not a security issue as long as you not getting any user input (otherwise  `sanitize/encrypt` your value).

Go ahead and use it like this

```
<?php
$_SESSION['next-page-id'] = get_the_ID(); // once set
```

Now in your whole application you can access your session variable like this:

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['next-page-id'] ) ) { // remember to check if it set or not
    echo $_SESSION['next-page-id'];
}
```

**Edited:**

You don't have to use `session_start()` on top of each page instead you should add a function in `init` hook.

Just paste this tiny code to your `functions.php` file

```
function session_initialize() {

    if ( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'session_initialize' );
```

> Is it possible for a user to view session variables?

No, a user can't able to view your session at all. If they don't have access to your files.

> How does wordpress stop users from creating their own session variables?

Remember Wordpress not use session in its whole application (Only Cookies). Users cannot create session variables. As said above they have to write code to your php file (or somehow they inject code to your application if any plugin or theme found vulnerable).

Comment: Thank you so much!This is exactly what I needed.
Also,had to add session_start(); at the top of each page I wanted to access that variable from.
Is it possible for a user to view session variables?How does wordpress stop users from creating their own session variables?Sorry about all the questions.

Comment: @RahilWazir - I accidentally rejected your edit to the question (didn't notice the additional tag).  Now I'm trying to figure out how to retract my reject vote - sorry about that

Comment: @RahilWazir Thank you.That makes much more sense to me.I have learned something good today.

Comment: @RahilWazir It looks like someone else approved it, so I guess you're good.  I'll throw in an upvote to compensate for any bother :)